# Repeating error code from jQuery

Tags: jquery

The below code works correctly but when I click the submit on my user login form with an incorrect user name and password I get this error:

> Incorrect Informatiın

Then I click submit again with incorrect values and this error message repeats over and over. Because of this my `div` strangely expands. How can I fix this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$("#giris").submit(function (event) {
    var kullanici_adi = $("#kullanici_ad").val();
    var sifre = $("#sifre").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "girisislemi.php",
        data: {
            kullanici_adi: kullanici_adi,
            sifre: sifre
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.tip === 'yonetici') {
                window.location.href = "yonetici.php";
            }
            if (data.tip === 'kullanici') {
                window.location.href = "kullanici.php";
            }
            if (data.tip === 'error') {
                $('input[type=text]').css("border", "3px solid red");
                $('input[type=password]').css("border", "3px solid red");
                $('#giris').after("<font><p>Incorrect Information </p><font>");
                $('font').css("color", "red");
            }

        }

    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier for both you and others to read, and means you'll get help quicker.

Comment: I will next time,thank you so much @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your use of `after()` which will always add new content each time it's run. Instead, you could check to see if the error has already been shown:

```
if (data.tip === 'error') {
    $('input[type=text], input[type=password]').addClass('login-error');
    if (!$('p.login-error').length)
        $('#giris').after('<p class="login-error">Incorrect Information </p>');
}
```

Also note that the `<font />` element is very outdated, and shouldn't be used any more, and you should set your styling rules in classes in a stylesheet and using add/removeClass instead of setting inline `css()`.

```
input.login-error {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
p.login-error {
    color: red;
}
```